# "I am Having validation.xml given below, what Is the validation-rules.xml for doing Validations In Struts Application

Tags: struts

> Blockquote

I am Using Following Validation.xml Is It Corret For Doing Validations
    For Inputting Name, Age, Email,Telephone In My Struts Application, what is the
    validation-rules.xml for it.............................**
    Please Help Me.....

> Blockquote

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE form-validation PUBLIC     
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Commons Validator Rules Configuration   
   1.1.3//EN"           
   "http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/dtds/validator_1_1_3.dtd"> 
   <form-validation> 
   <global>     
   <constant>     
   <constant-name>telephoneFormat</constant-name>     
   <constant-value>^\d{5,10}$</constant-value>     
   </constant> 
   </global> 
  <formset>     
  <form name="CustomerForm">         
  <field property="name" depends="required">             
  <arg key="label.name" />         
  </field>         
  <field property="age" depends="required, integer, intRange">  
  <arg0 key="label.age" />             
  <arg1 key="${var:min}" resource="false"/>
  <arg2 key="${var:max}" resource="false"/>             
  <var>                 
    <var-name>min</var-name>                 
    <var-value>1</var-value>             
 </var>             
 <var>                 
   <var-name>max</var-name>                 
   <var-value>125</var-value>             
 </var>         
</field>         
<field property="telephone" depends="required, mask">             
   <arg key="label.telephone" />             
   <arg1 key="label.telephone" />             
 <var>                 
   <var-name>mask</var-name>                 
   <var-value>${telephoneFormat}</var-value>             
 </var>         
</field>         
<field property="email" depends="email">             
  <arg0 key="label.email" />             
  <arg1 key="label.email" />         
</field>     
</form> 
 </formset> 
</form-validation>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as the validation.xml goes it looks alright to me. I hope you have made the necessary entries in MessageResources.properties file. Unless I'm mistaken you are using the above from another example on the web. I had come across it while searching for something about validation.xml.

If you have any queries do let me know as I have successfully done the validations.